# Clean all selected option after ajax request

Tags: jquery

Selecting values from drop-down according to the data that retrieved from Ajax request to database by clicking on update link and when i console.log the response i can see data has been retrieved and i am successfully able to compare it with drop-down list and if there is a match one of the option values will be selected.

If i click on clean button to clear the selected option, it works for the first time.

But if i click on the update link again to retrieved data i can see data has been retrieved when i console.log the response but nothing is selected from the drop-down.

Any help - here is my code down below

```
<p>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="updateCenter">Update</a>
</p>

<form method="post" action="controller/update" class="formInuts">
    <select required="" name="semester_id" class="form-control semester">
        <option value="">Pleas Select</option>
        <option value="1">Semester 1</option>
        <option value="2">Semester 2</option>
        <option value="3">Semester 3</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary saveCorCnt">SAve</button>
    <button type="" class="btn btn-primary clearCorCnt">Clean</button>
</form>


// Update 
$('.updateCenter').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // semester id
    var corcnt_id = 1;

    $.ajax({
        url: url+'/findcorcnt',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            corcntid: corcnt_id
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(respond) {
            // Data retrieved successfully 
            // first time and every time i click on update link
            // Changing the current action to update
            var formInuts = $('.formInuts').attr('action',url+'/updatecorcnt');

            // Change save btn to update
            var saveBtn   = $('.saveCorCnt').text('update');

            // Selecting the values from dropdowns semesters
            $('.semester option').each(function(){
                if (parseInt(this.value) == respond.semester_id) {
                    $(this).attr('selected', true);
                }
            });
        });


$('.clearCorCnt').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(':input','.formInuts')
        .removeAttr('checked')
        .removeAttr('selected')
        .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :radio, :checkbox')
        .val('');

    var saveBtn   = $('.saveCorCnt').text('save');
});
```

Comment: As a sidenote, when working with `checked`, `selected` etc. you want to work with the **properties** and not the attributes, i.e. use `.prop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to compare using loop. Just try like following.

```
$('.semester').val(respond.semester_id);
```

Comment: i thought i supposed to loop over and compare the values. :) i will try this